# Getting this error on compiling through webpack Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-devtools-extension

On compiling this code, I m getting this error **SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ","**. I hope you could help me with this. Error on line(13:39)

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducers from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore({
    rootReducers,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
});

export default store;
```

*Thank you*

Comment: add a `comma` `,` after this line `composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))`

Comment: that isn't a syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `createStore` is wrong. It should be a list of paramaters, not an object:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducers, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));
```

The correct function signature is:

```
 createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

see the docs [here](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore)